# Cannot connect MySQL WorkBench to MySQL server on M3 Mac. "SQL Logic Error" Pop up

Tags: mysql-workbench

On MySql Workbench, whenever I try to launch "Local instance 3306" It keeps giving me an unsupported sevrer pop-up. After a while of trying, I also got this pop-up. "Cannot Connect to Database Server - Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' to the MySQL server at localhost:3306:  SQL Logic Error"

SQL is currently installed and running on my device. In the terminal, I can see the databases created and execute certain commands. I originally thought it was an issue with the versions of SQL and WorkBench installed but after reinstalling the same versions for both (macOS 14 (ARM, 64-bit), DMG Archive), I still get this error. Whenever I test the connection, it says the workbench is successfully connected to the server. I thought it was an issue with the ports but They both are using port 3306. I read somewhere I should maybe try using 3307 but I do not know how to change the port in the terminal.

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you!